# How can i get the value “i” to work outside for loop

Tags: javascript

How can I get `i` to work in `habitButton.addEventListener`

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
    let numberElement = document.createElement("span");
    numberElement.classList.add("number");
      
    numberElement.textContent = i;
    numberBox.appendChild(numberElement);
 }

habitButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert(numberBox)
    if (i === go) {
      numberElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
    habitButton.classList.toggle("fa-square-check")
    //habitButton.className = "fas fa-check";
});
```

I have tried declaring `i` outside the loop but it did not work.

Comment: `habitButton` and  `go` are not defined. You should set the onClick after you do createElement in the loop.]

Comment: Also you are declaring numberElement as let. How you are expecting it to present in the habitButton listener? You need to declare them outside of block.

Comment: `i` has a different value for every iteration of that for loop **inside** the for loop. If you define it outside the loop then after the loop it will just have a value of 31. If you want to do anything with the values of `i`, you have to do it *inside* the loop body. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: `habitButton` and `numberElement` seem to be unrelated.  Do you have some HTML showing their relationship?

Comment: "it did not work" is not a sufficiently detailed description of what went wrong when you tried.  When asking a question, always give the exact text of any error you encountered, and describe in detail what your expected results are vs the actual results when you tried.  Also "how to get the value to **work** outside for loop" is vague.  What do you mean by _work_ in this case?  What do you expect the value of `i` to be? Are you expecting 32?  Give us more context about what `go` is and what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the `onclick` method before calling `appendChild`.

Seems like you're looking for this:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
    let numberElement = document.createElement("span");
    numberElement.classList.add("number");
    
    numberElement.onclick = function() {
        numberElement.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }

    numberElement.textContent = i;
    document.body.appendChild(numberElement);
}
```

```css
body { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
```

Comment: That is a lot of speculations...kudos if you guesed it right ;)